# React Component addition gets me NaN

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering, nan

my code gives me a NaN result after an addition rendering, do you know why?

```
const Total = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Number of exercises {props.exercises1 + props.exercises2 + props.exercises3}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const course = 'Half Stack application development'
  const part1 = {
    name: 'Fundamentals of React',
    exercises: 10
  }
  const part2 = {
    name: 'Using props to pass data',
    exercises: 7
  }
  const part3 = {
    name: 'State of a component',
    exercises: 14
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Total exercise1={part1.exercises} exercises2={part2.exercises} exercises3={part3.exercises} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**page looks like this**:

Half Stack application development

Fundamentals of React 10

Using props to pass data 7

State of a component 14

**Number of exercises NaN** <--- NaN

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have passed `exercise1`, `exercise2`, `exercise3` as props but then accessing them as `props.exercises1`, `props.exercises2`, `props.exercises3`.
Notice the extra s in excercise.

So it is undefined and when you try to add undefined Js return NaN

Comment: Hero of the day, thank you.

Comment: @hesburgerSuomi You can accept it as an answer if you want

Answer (score 1):

You're adding props.exercises1 which is undefined to the other exercises, your prop name is props.exercise1